# jquery trigger submit click not working in ff

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble trying to trigger a submit button in firefox 3.6 but it works in IE 8

```
        $('.triggerLink').click(function (event) {
            $('#submitBtn').trigger('click');
        });
```

I'm also using vs2010 and in Firebug it just says status=aborted on the Post with no Response or other indication what went wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your code, but I do want to point out that you can write the same code more concisely by omitting the `event` argument, and changing `.trigger('click')` to `.click()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to trigger a form submit. Instead of clicking the *Submit* button, why not just submit the form:

```
$('#submitBtn').closest('form').submit();
```

Or, if you know the `id` of the form:

```
$('#formID').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some comments in the documentation, other people have had the same issue.

[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

> As of jQuery 1.3, .trigger()ed events
>   bubble up the DOM tree; an event
>   handler can stop the bubbling by
>   returning false from the handler or
>   calling the .stopPropagation() method
>   on the event object passed into the
>   event. Although .trigger() simulates
>   an event activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, **it does not
>   perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event**.

As Matt mentioned above, why not just use .click()?

Comment: and @Matt The .click() doesn't work for IE or FF for me when using a $('submit').click()